# Isotop layout method not working on iOS 9 and iPhone 7 running iOS 10.1.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I've run into a very strange problem and have not been able to figure out the root of it. I've created a section on a client's wordpress site that shows employee profile summaries. Users can click "read more" link that expands the post on the same page.

I wrote some javascript (using jquery) that will replace the summary text with full article text, add a class to the element to make it full width, and then call isotope('layout') to readjust how the elements are arranged. But for some reason isotope('layout') is not firing on certain iOS devices, whether safari or chrome, making me think it's an iOS issue.

Here is a staged version of the page: http://udot-intranet.pennapowersdev.com/spotlights/

The code is located in scripts.js - here is the specific section that handles the read more functionality:

```
    //-------------- Read More Post Shortening -----------------//
    var read_more_click = false;

    $container.on( 'layoutComplete',
      function( event, laidOutItems ) {
        if(read_more_click){
            console.log("layoutComplete");
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $this_post.offset().top - 50
            }, 'fast', function(){
               $('html, body').off("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove");
            });

            $('html, body').on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
               $('html, body').stop();
           });
            read_more_click = false;
        }
      }
    );

    var $this_post = '';
    var post_scrollTop = 0;

    $(document).on("click", '.post_list .read_more', function(){
        $this_post = $(this).parents(".post_item");
        read_more_click = true;
        console.log('read more fired');
        if($this_post.hasClass("excerpt")) {
            $(this).text('< Read Less');
            $this_post.removeClass("excerpt");
            $this_post.addClass("full");
            $container.isotope('layout');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Read More >');
            $this_post.removeClass("full");
            $this_post.addClass("excerpt");
            $container.isotope('layout');
        }

        return false;
    });
```

Any insight into what's causing the problem would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Not sure the reasoning for this, but by removing the option "percentPosition" when initializing isotope it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the result of how mobile devices handle Javascript. Apple pauses execution of JS until AFTER scrolling is complete (they do this to reduce load and thus improve battery life). If the plugin script is not taking advantage of promises, it is very possible for a callback to be ignored during that JS pause.

I notice that you are calling scrollTop() when the read more is clicked. This will pause your script until the scrolling is complete and increase the chance of the callback getting missed. Try either using promises or place the relayout call inside a handler that check for scroll complete before firing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Korgrue. I've tried messing around with this, but even removing the scrollTop() animation completely doesn't fix the problem. I was able to replicate a similar functionality tweaking isotope's example code. [Here it is on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpEGgo). This does not have the same problems I'm having. Today I'll start getting my code to barebones to see if that helps.